# Microsoft Moles not generating moles and behaviors assemblies

Tags: .net, mstest, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I am having some issues with my machine actually generating moles assemblies.  Every tutorial I have run into has simply said the following steps:

1) Install it.

2) Right click a reference and click "Add Moles Assembly".

Following these steps it *should* generate a ".moles" file and also the set of assemblies as well.  My VS 2010 install generates the ".moles" file, but does not generate the assemblies (to my knowledge) at all-- or it just isn't adding them to the project file as a reference.  I am thinking it could be a problem with my Windows 7 install since it is a company build and they tend to like to lock things down.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried building your solution after you clicked "Add Moles Assembly"?

Comment: Yes, I have.  Also building, rebuilding, and also cleaning then building.

Comment: @JoshBarker What version of Visual Studio and .NET Framework are you using in your project?  This information will help us narrow down possible issues.  Thank you!

Comment: @MikeChristian I am using VS 2010 and I am trying to mole things on a MS Test project (C#) .NET 4.0.

Comment: By the way, my output merely says: -- Moles vs build action rebuild all started
-- Moles update finished

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need Administration Rights or a particular privelege? See this:

[Missing Add Moles assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609577/missing-add-moles-assembly)

Run Visual Studio with Administrator permission...either through the command-line, or change the Properties of your shortcut.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/pex/thread/364ac145-0c48-49e1-8ee8-fd549fee3184

---

UPDATE: For people that like to watch a short video on the steps needed to use Moles, see this:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Peli/Moles-Replace-any-NET-method-with-a-delegate

Also keep in mind they have given Moles a new name ... Microsoft Fakes Isolation Framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've tried a few things: uninstalling, "run as admin" and reinstalling.  Then "run as admin" for VS 2010.  I have admin rights, mostly, to my machine, but UAC is locked to my knowledge.

Comment: Could you try the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748101/moles-creation-does-not-create-all-objects

Comment: I can run via command line-- tried "run as admin" on cmd and execute command works.  If I don't run as admin, UAC has a heart-attack.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637866/has-anyone-made-moles-work-properly

Comment: @JoshBarker I just updated the answer linked by colinsmith, to include a new step (now step 3).  Please be aware the proper references must be present, for (what is now) step 4 to reliably execute step 4.

Comment: @colinsmith just walked through the steps... no go.  Added the reference to Microsoft.Moles.Framework which resides in the GAC (version 0.94.0.0). I also disabled UAC and still isn't working.